# Bronze, Silver, Gold, Platinum elo, what is it actually?

Tags: league-of-legends

I don't know what exactly are Bronze, Silver, Gold and Platinum elos. Does it have any other meaning than just a way to tell people how good you are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**WARNING**: This answer was based on a "leaked" list located on the forum which eventually turned out to be a hoax. The newly released information is available on the LOL forums The actual ELO tier system has changed significantly for season 2.

Along with the bragging rights, at the end of a season rewards are given to each elo. The season 1 rewards were the following:

> Platinum (Top 0.2%) - 1900 and above (3v3: 1700+, pre-made 5v5:
>   1750+): a framed 
>       summoner icon in platinum, a platinum banner in summoner profile, a platinum forum 
>       badge and a special skin for Jarvan IV
>
> Gold (Top 3%) - Between 1520 and 1899 (3v3: 1490-1699, pre-made 5v5:
>   1500-1749) : a 
>       framed summoner icon in gold, a gold banner in your summoner profile, a gold forum 
>       badge and a special skin for Jarvan IV
>
> Silver (Top 10%) - Between 1400 and 1519 (3v3: 1410-1489, pre-made
>   5v5: 1410-1499) : 
>       a framed summoner icon in silver and a silver banner in your summoner profile
>
> Bronze (Top 25%) - Between 1249 and 1399 (3v3: 1249-1409, pre-made
>   5v5: 1249-1409) : 
>       a bronze banner in your summoner profile

Source: http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1143351

**This information was a hoax perpetuated on the forums, and is confirmed false:**

The leaked season two list is as follows, but its not confirmed to be real:

> Bronze [1250-1399] 25% - Glorious Poppy [Skin] and a second layer of
>   bronze frame
>       on profile.
>
> Silver [1400-1519] 10% - Regifted Wukong [Skin] and a second layer of silver frame on
>       profile.
>
> Gold [1520 - 1899] 2% - Vandal Sivir [Skin] and a second layer of gold frame on 
>       profile.
>
> Platinum [1900+] 0.2% - Diamond Anivia [Skin] and a second layer of
>   platinum frame on 
>       profile.

Source: http://eune.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=459227

---

Each layer gets the skins from preceding layers as well. If a player does not have the champion for a skin, he also receives the champion.

Also, there is a fifth layer called "True platinum" at 2220+, where platinum originally started. It is visible as the platinum badge glows brightly on the profile screen. True plat has no rewards, it was added to keep 2220+ players happy when platinum was made easier to acquire. Season 1 true plat players received recognition on the website.

Comment: @pooh If an answer helps you, you should accept it by clicking the green checkmark :)

Comment: For what it's worth, the season 2 awards have been announced, and are fairly different than those listed in this answer: http://www.reignofgaming.net/blogs/a-different-view/vvinrar/21623-season-2-rewards-announced

Comment: All of what you just said above is 100% fake, the only skin they are giving is War Hero Janna for those above silver elo Read the red post at the end http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=8073152#8073152

Comment: At the time, it was the most plausible information. It had been cited in multiple places on the forums. As I did note in the comment, it had not been confirmed to be real. I will not delete the answer but will mark it as a hoax for the future.